# Debug, measure time image upload in django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I have a problem in my project in django (Django 1.8 - I know it is old) with photo uploading. The point is that this is too slow.

1. What could be the reason?
2. How can I debug, measure how long it takes? This should be checked on the nginx side?

Answer (score 0):

1. Body size (image size) could be huge and if you upload it without compression, it could take more time to send all data to handler.
2. Create decorator around handler that takes media uploads.